# Turtlebot does not always drive in a straight line

Tags: c++, ros, robotics

I have some C++ code in which i give the turtlebot a coordinate using:

```
goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = mypoint.point.x
goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = mypoint.point.y
```

The robot moves from one point to another. However only rarely does it do this in a straight line. It seems as though the turtlebot starts moving before it is done rotating. There aren't any obstacles in between the points. It is able to get to every point, but it tends to move in small arc between them.

**Any ideas on how to force the robot to move in a straight line, when there are no obstacles in its way?**

Edit: I use `turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` and `turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch`.

Comment: does it always move in arcs or only after it's been told to turn? I think the most likely explanation (though I haven't used a turtlebot myself) is that the wheels are moving at slightly different speeds (perhaps due to tolerances in wheel diameter), and it doesn't have a built-in gyroscope to automatically correct for the effect. Maybe there is a calibration process you can apply?

Comment: I agree with what Dave said. With almost any robot project I have worked on, getting the robot to drive straight is the single most hardest thing to do. You should check the outputs from your motors on a oscilloscope to see what their signal looks like and compare as well.

Comment: Thanks, but it does have a gyroscope, and it does move in a perfect straight line about 1/3 of the time. If i move the turtlebot with a controller, it can move in a perfectly straight line as well.

Comment: In that case, other than suggesting you try to narrow down the issue by performing different actions (e.g. turn, wait a few seconds, then move; or turn 360 and check it points back in the same direction), I'd suggest you might have better luck here: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/ (a robotics-focussed sister site to stackoverflow)

Comment: As Dave suggests, I think this may be more of a *[robotics.se]* question rather than a code question. Also answers such as http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/1234/37 and http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/10024/37 may already answer the general case for your question.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is what Dave suggested, that the wheels are moving at different speeds and a two-wheeled robot will follow an arc around the wheel that is moving slower. But this is not because of variations of the wheel diameter,  but because no two motors are identical (due to manufacturing) and therefore even the motors of the same model will have slight variations. Given the same current and voltage, the motors will drive at a slightly different speed; which makes the robot follow an arc.

The solution is in implement a feedback control, where you get the rotation feedback and implement the error in a simple control scheme such as PID control. Pseudocode for PID is as follows:

```
Kp = ..                                   //constant
    Loop forever
       read sensors    
       error = TargetValue - offset       
       integral = integral + error        // calculate the integral 
       derivative = error - lastError     // calculate the derivative
       Turn = Kp*error + Ki*integral + Kd*derivative  
       lastError = error                  // save the current error so it can be the lastError next time around
    end loop forever
```